# Problem about mp inverse

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Show that $ABB^+(ABB^+)^+=AB(AB)^+$.

This is an exercise from Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics. There are no other assumptions. I know if $|A|\neq 0$ , then $(AB)^+=B^+(ABB^+)^+$, and the above equation establishes.

Comment: What definition of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse have you been given?

Comment: X is the MP inverse of a real matrix A if: AXA = A, XAX=X, (AX)'=AX, (XA)'=XA

Comment: What is $B$? What is the rank?

Comment: Nothing special about B. No assumption about the rank.

Answer (score 0):

What precisely is the question?

You provide that for $\mathbf{A}\ne\mathbf{0}$, then
$$
%
\left( \mathbf{AB} \right)^{+} =
%
\mathbf{B}^{+}
\left( \mathbf{ABB}^{+} \right)^{+}
%
\tag{1}
$$

You note an immediate consequence of $(1)$ is
$$
%
\left( \mathbf{AB} \right)
\left( \mathbf{AB} \right)^{+} =
%
\left( \mathbf{AB} \right)
\mathbf{B}^{+}
\left( \mathbf{ABB}^{+} \right)^{+} =
%
\left( \mathbf{ABB}^{+} \right)
\left( \mathbf{ABB}^{+} \right)^{+}
%
\tag{2}
$$
which seems to be the result you are looking for.

Comment: The question is to prove  **_ABB+(ABB+)+=AB(AB)+_**  , **no more assumption**. I mean I know how to prove if there is assumption  **_A≠0_**  .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know how to prove it by Arin Chaudhuri's proof.

Answer (score 0):

For any real matrix $X$, $XX^{+}$ is **the** orthogonal projection matrix onto the column space of $X$.

It follows consequently that the LHS is the orthogonal projection matrix on the column space of $ABB^{+}$ and the RHS is the orthogonal projection matrix on the column space of $AB$.

So it is enough to show that $ABB^{+}$ and $AB$ have the same column space.

Clearly column space of $ABB^{+}$ is contained in column space of $AB$.
Now $AB = ABB^{+}B$, so the column space of $AB$ is also contained in the column space of $ABB^{+}$. Hence $AB$ and $ABB^{+}$ have the same column space and the result follows.

Comment: Oh I see.  (1) **_ABB+_** and **_AB_** have the same column space, (2) orthogonal projection matrix is unique. Thus establish the proof. Thanks for your help.